# jquery wouldn't load first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

my Jquery is not loading

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If I put jquery after bootstrap.min.js, jquery is loading however I need to load jquery first and when I do that I get:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery(…)

Answer (score 3):

Try with another order and close link css:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```